# Azure SDK || Blackduck has detected security vulnerability on io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.52.Final

Tags: azure, sdk

I am using azure-security-keyvault-secrets SDK to connect to Azure keyvault in the spark scala application.  The SDK Version we are using is 4.2.3, and it has netty-handler as a transitive dependency  io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.52.Final. Blackduck has detected security vulnerability on io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.52.Final.

We tried with the latest version of azure-security-keyvault-secrets 4.3.7, for that too blackduck shows the same vulnerability.

Please let us know, if there is any plan in microsoft end to provide this azure-security-keyvault-secrets SDK by fixing the security vulnerability.

Comment: You can open an issue on GitHub: [azure-sdk-for-java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues )